# Sharepoint 2013 Server Farm has duplicate servers of same machine one having name of IP address and other as hostname

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Recently our Sharepoint server 2013 database was upgraded from SQL server 2008 R2 to SQL server 2012 SP4. This has resulted in several issues.

1. There now two servers created in a single server farm one representing IP address and the other having host name. Both of the servers are having full set of services. Earlier it was only one server showing the host name
2. The search service is not running.
3. The Start and Stop of services on the server with IP address completes successfully, but on the server having the host name get stuck on starting or stopping stage.
4. Recreation of service applications like search service or user profile service also gets stuck and never complete
5. There are also  two timer service instances, one for each machine, but starting or stopping any of them never gets completed and remains stuck.

What I want.

1. Only one server in the farm showing host name
2. All the services working i.e not getting stuck in starting stopping and service application like search and user profile working.

Server has just one application for port 80 and one for CA
This is a production server and each day 1500  to 2000 tasks are generated and similar number of workflows are run this means I cant risk outage.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Imran

Comment: Search Service was always giving error of not being able to connect to administration component. Checked the administration component server fields were null. Tried several times by recreating search services but always reached same dead end.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved Search Service Issue**
Stored the Search Service Application

```
$ssa=Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceapplication -Identity XXXXXXX
```

Stored Service instance

```
$si =  $ssa.service.Instances
```

Noticed that the proxy for Search service application was also not created
created proxy

```
$proxy=New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -SearchApplication $ssa
```

Set the admin component by

```
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent -SearchApplication $ssa -SearchServiceInstance $si
```

Noticed that Search Administration Web Service for Search Service Application was showing Stopped and Search Service Application was showing Error status, started by

```
$ssa.Provision()
```

Checked the status of both the Service Applications it was showing started

Checked the admin component by

```
$ssa.AdminComponent
```

It was showing server name

At least one of my problems was solved and my users are able to do searches. I still have to resolve other issues.